# PHP - Strange result when compare 2 float values

Tags: php, compare

I am trying to compare 2 values in PHP.

My logic is:

1. I have a remaining amount (a)
2. I have a amount to be charged (b)
3. I calculate remaining to be by ( a - b )
4. After charge action I get the actual remaining value (c)
5. I compare the value I got in #3 with (c)

Even though the both are similar PHP says they are not equal.

Below given is my code (with filled values)

```
<?php
$remaining_amount_before_payment = "600";
$remaining_amount_after_payment = (float)$remaining_amount_before_payment - (float)"387.60";
$actual_remaining_amount_after_payment = "212.4";
echo "actual_remaining_amount_after_payment: {$actual_remaining_amount_after_payment} <br><br>";
echo "remaining_amount_after_payment: {$remaining_amount_after_payment} <br><br>";
var_dump( ((float)$actual_remaining_amount_after_payment) == ((float)$remaining_amount_after_payment) );?>
```

I type cast the values to `float`, but the `var_dump` returns `FALSE`.

Can anybody help me to find out why this is?

I am using PHP 5.6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) why do you write your numbers as strings in the first place? there is absolutly **no** reason ever to do that. b) you do know that floating point arithmetics are *not* precise? you know and have read the [floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/)? c) and as you said yourself: "Even though the both are similar PHP says they are not equal." - you know that "similar" and "equal" are not the same? ;)

Comment: Because the actual values I am getting is from a API and they come as strings! That's why I cast them to `float` since I have no control over the API response!
I did not know about the point (b) you said. Is it not good to use `float` to type cast?

Answer (score 1):

Bingo!

After several attempts I caught the catch. I was going crazy.

The "problem" is inside the right rounding values

```
$remaining_amount_before_payment = floatval("600"); // use floatval istead of (float)
$remaining_amount_after_payment = round($remaining_amount_before_payment - floatval("387.60"), 2);// use floatval istead of (float) and round result
$actual_remaining_amount_after_payment = floatval("212.4");// use floatval
echo "actual_remaining_amount_after_payment: {$actual_remaining_amount_after_payment} <br><br>";
echo "remaining_amount_after_payment: {$remaining_amount_after_payment} <br><br>";

var_dump( $actual_remaining_amount_after_payment === $remaining_amount_after_payment ); // return TRUE
```

**[Example](http://rextester.com/JNYSEY94650)**

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

Use var_dump(abs(floatval($actual_remaining_amount_after_payment) == floatval($remaining_amount_after_payment)) == 0);

Answer (score 0):

acual your variable '$remaining_amount_after_payment' is not realy 212.4

use a var_export to determine its value.
In my concern, You should "round" your floats values to a precision. [round(x, precision)](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php) for comparison